# SharePoint Site url is not working for debugging a solution

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, alternate-access-mapping

For debugging a SharePoint solution I want to give test site URL in visual studio.

[image]

but since web application URL is already access mapped

```
(http://example:2344 -> http://example.com).
```

When I try to give http://example.com URL in, it shows

> "Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported "

[image]

How can I use http://example.com (Alternate Access Mapped Url) for debugging purpose since currently, I don't have original URL (http://example:2344)?

Comment: do you have access to central admin ?

Comment: yes i am working on Dev environment so i have access to central admin .

Comment: then you can determine the internal url of you application and use the same for debugging.

Comment: In Alternate Access Mapping ->Edit Public Zone URLs , it is showing only http://example.com . Can you please tell me where to find http://example:2344 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to configure the **hosts file** on your server to map the server IP to the hostname.

---

**To Edit Host file**

- Open your NotePad as administrator.
- From Notepad, open the following file: `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
- Add new entry as the following:

  - Server IP > click Tab > hostname , for example:

    ```
    127.0.0.1     example.com
    ```
- Click File > Save to save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

use the  `Get-SPAlternateURL` cmdlet, you can find the existing AAM settings for a web application.

Comment: It is showing example.com(IncomingUrl) and example.com(PublicUrl).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

1)Open the project path in Windows Explorer

2)Locate the file .csproj.user(or .vbproj.user)

3)Open it with text editor(e.g. Notepad)

4)Change the SharePointSiteUrl property

5)Save the file, and then re-open the project (by deploying)

This works perfectly for me..

Thanks Jinchun Chen